# Relation between derivative of expanding circle map and distance between points in the preimage

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, metric-spaces, dynamical-systems

Consider $S^1$ as $\mathbb R/\mathbb Z$ with metric $d(x,y)=\min\{|x-y|,1-|x-y||\}$. I have been motivated by [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2543095/mean-value-theorem-for-the-circle/2543278?noredirect=1#comment5251781_2543278) other question of mine to understand how the derivate of a self map $f:S^1\to S^1$ effects the dynamics (derivative here defined in terms of charts as in the link). After quite a few hours of Googling I have been unable to find a source that deals with this at a level I can understand. So my question is two-fold. First I would appreciate it if anyone can recommend a source discussing these issues at a level that can be followed by someone who knows about a one semester course's worth of smooth manifold theory, an intermediate amount of functional analysis and a standard bachelor's degree in pure maths.

Secondly, at the moment I am specifically interested whether $|f'(x)|$ affects the distance between the points in any preimage under $f$. I am motivated by the expanding circle endomorphism $E_m(x)=mx\mod 1$, with $m>1$. To keep in line with that motivation let us consider $f:S^1\to S^1$ is a surjective circle map, with the property that for all $x\in S^1$ there exists a isometry $\gamma_x:U_x\to (a,b)_x$ from a neighbourhood of $x$ to an interval $(a,b)_x$. Furthermore assume that for each $x$ we have that $f(U_x)\subseteq U_{f(x)}$, $\gamma_{f(x)}\circ f\circ \gamma_x^{-1}$ is differentiable, and, for all $x\in S^1$, $f'(x):=(\gamma_{f(x)}\circ f\circ \gamma_x^{-1})'\circ\gamma_x>1+\delta$ for some $\delta>0$.

For such an $f$, can we say that the distance between any two points in the preimage of any $x$ under $f$ must be less than $\frac{1}{\inf_{S^1}f'(x)}$? If not, can we strengthen our assumptions to make this so?

Comment: Sorry for saying but you are complicating this a bit too much: expanding maps are local diffeomorphisms and so all works as in the usual change of variables formula, provided that we stay in the domain of the local diffeomorphism. For larger sets you just need to patch them.

Comment: @JohnB I don't see how the change of variables formula can help find the maximum distance between points in the preimage in this case? Please elaborate if you can.